# How to specify actions performed by syncdb?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I need to make some installation action (create a table record) after `python manage.py syncdb` finishes it's work (just like when you `syncdb` with imported `django.cotrib.auth.models.User` and it asks to create a superuser). Where do i need to place the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps that you need is [providing initial data for models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/) with fixtures.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the [post_syncdb signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/signals/#post-syncdb).

Comment: I have tried this too, thanks, this is a much more flexible way. And i like it more because App Install actions remain incapsulated